# Calculating geolocation for pixels from a tile (Mercator projection)

Tags: java, geolocation, maps, tile, mercator

Assume you have a 256x256 tile denoted with it's zoom level and coordinates in it.

```
val tile = Tile(x, y, z)
```

How could one get geolocation for specific pixel in that tile?

That is, how to calculate `LatLngLocation(lat, lng)` for `Pixel(i, j)` in tile specified with `Tile(x, y, z)`?

Just to be clear, both `i` and `j` are in range `[0, 255]`.

Edit: `x` and `y` are tile numbers at magnification level `z`.

Comment: Are the coordinates of the `Tile` related to the center of the `Tile`?

Comment: And is `z` essentially just the level of magnification? (i.e. the distance from the ground that the "camera" is located?)